# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'select2'

Tags: javascript, php, yii, autocomplete, yii-extensions

I am trying to use "SELECT2" extension with YII. I followed the tutorial step by step but it's not working.  The drop-down list for auto-complete doesn't appear and I am getting this error in chrome console...

The controller code (HotelController)

```
public function actionTitleName(){
    $model =HotelEn::model()->findAll ('Title like :Title',array(':Title'=>"%".$_GET['q']."%")); 
    $result = array();
    foreach ($model as $HotelEn){
        $result[] = array(
            'id'=>$HotelEn->id,
            'term'=>$RoomEn->Number,
        ); 
    }
    echo CJSON::encode($result);
}
```

the view code (_roomearch)

```
echo CHtml::beginForm(CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('Hotel/create')), 'get', array('id'=>'filter-form'))
    . '<div class="row" style="width:100%;">'
    . CHtml::encode('Hotel Name')
    . CHtml::textField('Number',(isset($_GET['Number'])) ? $_GET['Number'] : '',array('id'=>'Number'));
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
    'selector' => '#Title',
    'options'  => array(
        'allowClear'=>true,
        'placeholder'=>'Select a Hotel Name',
        'minimumInputLength' => 2, 
        'ajax' => array(
            'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl('Hotel/Number'),
            'type'=>'GET',
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'quietMillis'=> 100,
            'data' => ' function(term,page) {
                return {
                    //get im my controller
                    q: term, 
                };
            }',
            'results'=>'function(data,page) { return {results: data, more:more }; }',
        ),
    ),
));         
echo '</div>'
```

Comment: your question doesn't disclose enough information.  I advise you look at your code, do a find for ->select2

Comment: I just want to have an autocoplete on my search field by using the select2 extention. the prob is tha it's supposed to suggest some result in a dropdownlist when I input something. but is doesn't show. and when i checked chrome console it shows me this result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today.  I received the "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'select2'" error message in my browser console as well as a warning about a deprecated method in another .js file I was referencing (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js).  Turns out I wasn't even using it! so I deleted the script which referenced it, removing the warning.

Fixing the warning made my select2 problem go away.

a few things to help you trace what's wrong.

1. Are you able to get select2 to work in the most trivial of situations? (strip everything else from the page and ONLY use a select2 droplist to make sure your select2 libraries are working)
2. If you can get #1 to work I'd wager you have some javascript in another file which is interfering with your select2 droplist. Disable other js features one at a time to see which one is the culprit.
3. Good luck!  keep an eye on your console and network tabs to be sure your js libraries are loading and don't have errors or warnings.

Comment: thank you for your help I'll try your advice and hope it'll work

Comment: Also improver jQuery loading (eg. loading it by mistake multiple times) can lead to a such error.

Answer (score 0):

Your text field's `id` and your select2's `selector` do not match. You should change the `selector` to `#TitleName` or the text field `id` to `Title`.

Comment: thank you for the reply, but still have the same prob

Comment: Is the `select2` javascript being loaded?

Comment: yes when i take a look at the chrome console or fierbug select2.js is loaded and when i input the full name i get the right result which means that the searching function is correct, but the select2 autocomplete doesn't work and keep showing the same js erro in console